# Different types in release and debug in C#

Tags: c#

I've got some performance / memory critical code that uses floats. In debug mode I'd like to use decimals, as it makes it easier to verify calculations are correct.

Obviously I could do:

```
#if DEBUG
        decimal x;
#else
        float x;
#endif
```

It would however involve doing this in numerous places, and it seems a bit cumbersome. I was wondering if there was a better way? I can't just create my own type that descends from one or the other depending on the build settings, as they're sealed classes. I also don't want to be casting left right and centre, as I said before, it's performance critical.

I basically want to be able to say.

```
#if DEBUG
        MyType = decimal;
#else
        MyType = float;
#endif

MyType x;
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll have a hard time to find bugs on release mode. Especially, if you use `x` in financial calculations. Also, unit tests created for debug mode won't apply to release mode.

Comment: It seems like a really bad idea to have types with such different behaviours between debug and release.

Comment: As @PLB alludes to, it is a bad idea to have fundamental difference between development code and released code. You're asking for surprises.

Comment: If I was worried about the precision of calculations in release mode, I certainly wouldn't be using floats. As said, memory and performance critical. And if I can establish a way to define the type in just one place, then it's easy for me to switch to floats in debug mode if I wish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using System;
#if DEBUG
using MyType = System.Decimal;
#else
//Float
using MyType = System.Single;
#endif
```

You can define any type using the `using` keyword and the use it:

```
MyType x = 19.2;
MyType y = 19.2;
MyType d = x + y;
```

Comment: As this is going in as a using clause, I assume I need to add it to the top of every unit? Ideally I'd like to be able to have a single definition in one place.

Comment: Yes, that's right, you should do it in every file in which you want to use your own type.

Comment: Thanks for that, not quite what I was hoping for, but better than my possible alternative.